# How exactly does a ServerSocket behave in these scenarios?

Tags: java, sockets, router, serversocket, nat

Say we have a ServerSocket and we run accept(). A client connects and a new socket is created with the same local port as ServerSocket. Say the client sends data to this socket. It reaches the port, and reaches the java application. How does the data from here get to the correct socket?

Say two computers are hidden behind the same public IP via NAT. Would that end up creating problems? Would it seem as though the same computer is trying to create a connection (same public ip and same port) I feel as though I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you asking how Network Address Translation works? Or how routing works at all?

Comment: I think this question is fairly broad, maybe too much so for this site.  It might be better if you asked one single question that you were having issues with.  The best way to answer this is for you to read the relevant RFCs.  TCP/IP, NAT and routing are large, complex subjects, there a lot that goes on here.  (I'm not going to down vote though.)

Comment: Alright I will edit and leave it at one question. Im kind of asking two questions, but they are related. Im asking that would it create a problem if two computers are hidden behind the same public IP, would this look like it is the same computer or? Im also asking how is the socket decided. Data reaches the port and say there are two sockets on that port, how does it know which one to send the data too. And what is in charge of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A socket connects a local *address and port* with a remote *address and port*. This is key: you can accept multiple connections from the same IP as long as the *port* is different. (For example, you can open the same web page in two different browser tabs since they connect with two different client-side ports.)

The NAT is responsible for making sure that two connections from two separate computers receive a different address/port combination. If they are mapped to the same public IP, the NAT will need to assign a different local port for those connections. As a server, you shouldn't have to worry about this: you simply see two different address/port combinations connecting to your server's address/port, so they're different sockets.

In Java, a `ServerSocket` acts as an entry point. It binds to your server's address and port, so it's kind of a template for "half of a socket". When a client connects with their address and port, a "full" `Socket` is created with their half filled in and now the server and client can start talking. Look into how TCP/UDP connections work if that's still not clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have two servers with identical pair (IP, port). If behind a NAT, NAT should assign a different public port to each local server, it cannot assign it to both.

Comment: There can't *be* both, so the NAT device cannot have this problem in the first place. It's irrelevant.